# Access: Inventory Management with 2 seperate criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, system, inventory

im a bit of a newbie in access and i hope im not asking a stupid question. I have recently had to move an inventory system from excel to access. Each product is recipted in tbl.rct and has an order number a lot number quantity and expiry.

Each individual lot number needs to be verified before it can be recipted this information is on tbl.lot.

While making a form to receipt products i noticed that i couldnt add any products without their lot number already on lot.tbl - is there a way to get around this?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fugx.jpg

Attached relationships

Comment: Any table in a relational system can only ever have **at most --1--** primary key - you **cannot** have multiple primary keys.....

Comment: It would help to understand your problem if you make a screenshot of your relationship window, and of your form. Upload them to https://imgur.com/ and edit your post to add the links.

Comment: Added the realationships for you. Even if i could get rid of the lots table as i just need realtionship to show that an ordercode could have a large number of lot numbers and be able to count the number of each individual lot number that was recieved- issued

Answer (score 0):

I think you mix between Excel and the Access. These Table imported directly from the excel without any requirement change to meet Access Goals. The Database use to reduce the repeat routine work. The Tables that most be (Products, Order, Receipts, Lot must be Stock and collect data of (Qty, lot#, expiry, damage). Now we make sequence to how insert to Database. Open New Receipt to include in the stock the Product(link ID) and the detail. This is now in the warehouse. For selling you will make invoice when select product will show you the Lot available and its expiry and of course you select filter to filter on FIFP LIFO.
You can send me the excel file to convert to database if yes please provide me more information because the flow not clear well